# Cреднее количество рабочих часов за день

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Пример таблицы:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Empl_Name | Direction | Date_Time           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| a1        |         1 | 2017-03-18 10:00:00 |
| a1        |         0 | 2017-03-18 11:00:00 |
| a1        |         1 | 2017-03-19 12:00:00 |
| a1        |         0 | 2017-03-19 13:00:00 |
| a2        |         1 | 2017-03-19 07:00:00 |
| a2        |         0 | 2017-03-19 07:00:20 |
| a2        |         1 | 2017-03-19 14:00:00 |
| a2        |         0 | 2017-03-19 14:00:40 |
| a3        |         1 | 2017-03-19 10:00:00 |
| a3        |         0 | 2017-03-19 10:00:10 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

**Пример ответа**: a1 проводит на рабочем месте 7200/30 секунд в месяц и у него нет длинных перерывов, a2 проводит 60/30 secs нет длинных перерывов, a3 проводит 10/30 секунд нет длинных перерывов.

Upd:
Вот пример моего решения, но явно можно проще

```
                    FROM empl sub
                    WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                          AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                          AND sub.Direction = 1)        AS TimeInRank
                 FROM empl t
                 WHERE t.Direction = 1) AS ins
                INNER JOIN
                (SELECT
                   t.Empl_Name,
                   DATE_FORMAT(t.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `TimeInDate`,
                   t.Date_Time                          AS `Date_Time_Out`,
                   (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM empl sub
                    WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                          AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                          AND sub.Direction = 0)        AS TimeOutRank
                 FROM empl t
                 WHERE t.Direction = 0) AS outs
                  ON ins.Empl_Name = outs.Empl_Name AND ins.TimeInRank = outs.TimeOutRank
                     AND DATE_FORMAT(ins.Date_Time_In, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(outs.Date_Time_Out, '%Y-%m-%d')
              WHERE Date_Time_In BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(
                  LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
              GROUP BY ins.Empl_Name, DATE_FORMAT(ins.Date_Time_In, '%Y-%m-%d')
            ) t1
       GROUP BY Empl_Name
     ) main LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                         s1.Empl_Name,
                         1 AS Has_Long_Breaks
                       FROM (
                              SELECT
                                ins.Empl_Name,
                                ins.TimeInDate,
                                TimeInRank,
                                TimeOutRank,
                                Date_Time_In,
                                Date_Time_Out
                              FROM
                                (SELECT
                                   t.Empl_Name,
                                   DATE_FORMAT(t.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `TimeInDate`,
                                   t.Date_Time                          AS `Date_Time_In`,
                                   (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM empl sub
                                    WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                                          AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                                          AND sub.Direction = 1)        AS TimeInRank
                                 FROM empl t
                                 WHERE t.Direction = 1) AS ins
                                JOIN
                                (SELECT
                                   t.Empl_Name,
                                   DATE_FORMAT(t.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `TimeInDate`,
                                   t.Date_Time                          AS `Date_Time_Out`,
                                   (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM empl sub
                                    WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                                          AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                                          AND sub.Direction = 0)        AS TimeOutRank
                                 FROM empl t
                                 WHERE t.Direction = 0) AS outs
                                  ON ins.Empl_Name = outs.Empl_Name AND ins.TimeInRank = outs.TimeOutRank
                                     AND DATE_FORMAT(ins.Date_Time_In, '%Y-%m-%d') =
                                         DATE_FORMAT(outs.Date_Time_Out, '%Y-%m-%d')
                              WHERE Date_Time_In BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
                                                                     '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(
                                  LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
                            ) s1
                         JOIN (
                                SELECT
                                  ins.Empl_Name,
                                  ins.TimeInDate,
                                  TimeInRank,
                                  TimeOutRank,
                                  Date_Time_In,
                                  Date_Time_Out
                                FROM
                                  (SELECT
                                     t.Empl_Name,
                                     DATE_FORMAT(t.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `TimeInDate`,
                                     t.Date_Time                          AS `Date_Time_In`,
                                     (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                      FROM empl sub
                                      WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                                            AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                                            AND sub.Direction = 1)        AS TimeInRank
                                   FROM empl t
                                   WHERE t.Direction = 1) AS ins
                                  JOIN
                                  (SELECT
                                     t.Empl_Name,
                                     DATE_FORMAT(t.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `TimeInDate`,
                                     t.Date_Time                          AS `Date_Time_Out`,
                                     (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                      FROM empl sub
                                      WHERE sub.Date_Time <= t.Date_Time
                                            AND sub.Empl_Name = t.Empl_Name
                                            AND sub.Direction = 0)        AS TimeOutRank
                                   FROM empl t
                                   WHERE t.Direction = 0) AS outs
                                    ON ins.Empl_Name = outs.Empl_Name AND ins.TimeInRank = outs.TimeOutRank
                                       AND DATE_FORMAT(ins.Date_Time_In, '%Y-%m-%d') =
                                           DATE_FORMAT(outs.Date_Time_Out, '%Y-%m-%d')
                                WHERE Date_Time_In BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,
                                                                       '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(
                                    LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
                              ) s2 ON s1.Empl_Name = s2.Empl_Name
                       WHERE s1.TimeInDate = s2.TimeInDate AND s1.TimeInRank = s2.TimeOutRank + 1 AND
                             TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s2.Date_Time_Out, s1.Date_Time_In) > 3600) longBreaks
    ON main.Empl_Name = longBreaks.Empl_Name;
```

Comment: Как то на учебное задание смахивает ... что вы сами пытались сделать  , с какими сложностями столкнулись. И почему указано 2 разных СУБД ? Подход к решению в принципе одинаков, получить в одной строке текущую дату и из предыдущей записи. Но вот реализация этого сильно различна на postgresql (`lag()`) и mysql (переменные)

Comment: Да, это и есть учебное задание.
Я написал запрос на 129 строчек на mysql, он кое-как работает, но как-то слишком сложно.

Comment: Да, выглядит как то жутковато :) так какими средствами СУБД можно пользоваться, мне например `lag()` из оконных функций postrgesql очень нравится для подобной задачи

Comment: Изменение структуры данных не предлагать?

Comment: А что у вас за `count()` в запросе, по условиям задачи вроде считать ничего не надо было

Comment: Действительно lag() очень круто выглядит для решения для задачи.
К сожалению, я не работал раньше с postgre, но решение должно выглядеть так:
 ` Отсортировать по работнику, отсортировать по дате. Для каждой соседней записи одного работника вычесть время его работы.  Каждую разность проссуммировать для каждого работника за последний месяц. Если хоть одна разница больше часа, то вывести для работника флаг.`

Comment: Почему вы пишите, что у a2 нет длинных перерывов. он вышел 2017-03-19 07:00:20 и в тот же день вошел 2017-03-19 14:00:00 т.е. перерыв составил чуть меньше 7 часов ...

Comment: `Если сотрудник входит, то он обязательно выходит в тот же день. В течение одного дня сотрудник может неоднократно входить и выходить.` Этим условиям не противоречит два входа, а потом два выхода подряд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаем на стандартном SQL, функции работы с временем в нотации MySQL (во всех СУБД они свои).

Получаем все входы сотрудника, для каждого из низ подзапросом достаем следующий по времени выход и следующий вход в тот же день (возврат с перерыва). Следующий = минимальное время из всех, которые больше данного. Даты для удобства расчетов сразу переводим в секунды.

```
select empl_name,month,
       sum(outp-inp) work_time,
       sum(ninp-outp>=3600) big_break
  from (
select empl_name, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_time) as month,
       unix_timestamp(date_time) inp,
       (select unix_timestamp(min(date_time))
          from empl b
         where b.empl_name=a.empl_name and b.direction=0
           and b.date_time>a.date_time
       ) outp,
       (select unix_timestamp(min(date_time))
          from empl b
         where b.empl_name=a.empl_name and b.direction=1
           and b.date_time>a.date_time
           and to_days(b.date_time)=to_days(a.date_time)
       ) ninp
  from empl a
 where a.direction=1
) A
group by empl_name,month
```

Я решил выводить просто суммы времени работы и количество долгих отсутствий. Как считать среднее за месяц сами прикиньте, возможно надо сгруппировать сначала до дня, получить время работы в день и потом взять из них среднее (`avg()`), может еще как, смотря что такое "среднее за месяц". Получение количества больших перерывов выполнено в традиции MySQL (`sum(ninp-outp>=3600)`), для "стандартной" СУБД надо применять `case when`.